# How to stop LaTeX from breaking math mode lines?

Tags: math, latex

I keep encountering an awkward problem when I type out expressions in LaTeX where the text line in the compiled document cuts an expression/equation/math object in half. Of course, I make use of $$ $$ tags to ensure this doesn't happen for particularly hefty expressions or computations, but this isn't appropriate for small expressions that appear in expository text.

Is there something I can do to make sure LaTeX never chops a mathmode expression in half in the compiled document?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10850/stop-latex-from-breaking-an-inline-math-equation – the TLDR is to put the math expression into braces `{...}`.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `\mbox` around your equation

```
\mbox{$E = mc^2$}
```

This will prevent a line break in the equation if it is located close to the max text width, but may lead to the equation reaching over the end of the text body.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution just appending a tilde ~ to equations.
Example borrowed from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/545295/221435)

Instead of

```
  $x = \{x\,|\,x\in\mathbb{R_{\ge0}}\}$
```

you would write

```
  $~{x = \{x\,|\,x\in\mathbb{R_{\ge0}}\}}$
```

Comment: It somewhat works, but the problem is that it adds a space before the equation. Hence the negative vote I guess.